# How to specify table name in Fluent NHibernate ClassMap class?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am newbie to NHibernate and trying to use Fluent for mapping. My entity class name is different from the database table name it has to be mapped to.
I am using mapping class derived from `ClassMap<>`, but I can't specify the table name: the property `TableName` from `ClassMap` is read-only.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `Table("table_name")` instead.

Comment: This is now. As of Sept 2009 
Table("table_name");

Answer (score 6):

Does it work like?

```
public class UserAccountMap : ClassMap<UserAccount> {
    public UserAccountMap() {
        Table("User");
        Id(x => x.UserID, "UserID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.FirstName, "FirstName").Length(50)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.LastName, "LastName").Length(50)
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Comment: User is a reserved keyword. enclose with `. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2879630/475882

Answer (score 6):

The example above lead me in the right direction. This worked for me. My class name is "Party" and my table name is "prty.Party".

```
public class PartyMap : ClassMap<Party>
{
    public PartyMap()
    {
     Table("prty.Party");
     Id(x => x.PartyID);
     Map(x => x.PartyTypeLID);
     Map(x => x.OrganizationTypeLID);
     Map(x => x.PreferredContactMethodLID);
     Map(x => x.PrimaryLanguageLID);
     Map(x => x.PartyVID);
     Map(x => x.BeginDate);
     Map(x => x.EndDate);
     Map(x => x.RowDescriptor);
     Map(x => x.RowModifiedDate);
     Map(x => x.RowModifiedBy);
     Map(x => x.RowCreatedDate);
     Map(x => x.RowCreatedBy);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Maybe exists some way to skip all this map calls?