# Fluent NHibernate Column Mapping with Reserved Word

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've read that using a back tick ` should allow for using of reserved words. I'm using SQL Server and Fluent NHibernate and have a column name "File". If I map it with

```
"`File"
```

it tries using

```
[Fil]
```

so it's adding the brackets correctly, but dropping the "e" from the end. If I map it as

```
"`Filee"
```

it uses

```
[File]
```

correctly.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in NHibernate or Fluent Nhibernate?

Comment: Have you tried with out doing any thing with the fluentNHibernate.  If you export the hbm file fluentNHibernate will write table="`File`" for you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to put ` on both sides, like this:

```
"`File`"
```

As @Astaar says, the full syntax is:

```
Map(x => x.File).Column("`File`");
```

Comment: Oh my that took a long time for an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Square brackets also work:
Map(x => x.File).Column("[File]");

Comment: @Chronozoa do you know if that's a recent addition? I swear I tried that way back in 2010 when I answered this question and it didn't work.

Comment: @MatthewTalbert I do not know.  I am still very new to nHibernate.

Comment: Square brackets did not work, backticks _did_ work for us. NHibernate 5.2.6, FluentNHibernate 2.1.2. These posts are gold when working with old stuff.

Answer (score 5):

To be perfectly clear, the exact syntax would be

```
Map(x => x.File).Column("`File`");
```

Answer (score 5):

There are non manual configuration options for this as covered here: [NHibernate: forcing square brackets in schema export?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104563/nhibernate-forcing-square-brackets-in-schema-export/4105924#4105924)

as well as an alternative: [Fluent NHibernate and PostgreSQL, SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns - System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438491/fluent-nhibernate-and-postgresql-schemametadataupdater-quotetableandcolumns-s)

E.g.  `SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns(cfg)` which in FluentNhibernate would look something like

```
var config = Fluently.Configure()
   ...
   ...
   .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns);
```

Comment: I think this solution is better because it's a one time setting instead of adding all new column names being reserverd words specifically in each map.