# NHibernate: forcing square brackets in schema export?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there a way to tell NHibernate to use square brackets for all table and column names (like `[MyColumn]`) when generating the SQL schema export for MS SQL Server? I have a legacy database that uses reserved names for certain columns and running the SQL script generated using NH throws an error because of it.

I want to avoid having to specify this separately for each column.

UPDATE: I'm using the correct dialect:

```
MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(connectionString)
```

UPDATE 2: @UpTheCreek pointed me in the right direction - backticks, which helped me find the answer in the "**NHibernate in Action**" book (p. 76):

> There is no way, apart from quoting all table and column names in backticks, to force NHibernate to use quoted identifiers everywhere.

Comment: You could write a custom dialect. But personally, I'd just add the backticks manually ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easier approach:

```
SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns(config)
```

(Before building SessionFactory)

That will quote all the reserved names automatically.

Comment: There seem to be a better solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438491/fluent-nhibernate-and-postgresql-schemametadataupdater-quotetableandcolumns-sy

Comment: @Nux: why do you think it's better?

Comment: Better in terms of completness and it also seems to only escape what is needed to be escaped (keywords).

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks in your mapping files around the column names.  NH should replace these with the correct character for your db dialect (in your case square brackets).

i.e. use:

```
<class name="SomeClass" table="`SomeTable`">
```

NB - It won't work with an apostrophe.  The backtick is located top left on most keyboards.

Comment: I'm actually using Fluent NH, but I've tried it and backticks work there too. Although it doesn't really do what I asked for (a general approach and not having to do it separately for each name), I'll accept your answer since it pointed me to a page in the NH in Action book where the answer lies. Thanks

Comment: @Igor: Did you find a general approach?  I would have though you would need to customise the dialiect for that.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: see my updated question. Yes, I presume (over)writing the dialect would do the trick, but I guess backticks are a simpler solution for my current problem :)

Comment: @Igor, yeah, seems a little extreme! :)

Comment: @Igor if you're using Fluent NH, see: [Conventions](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use (or write) the correct dialect for your database