# Naming Table and Columns in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, postgresql, naming, fluent

I tried to change the table and column names of my Employee entity by accessing the Table("") and Column("") attributes of its classmap in fluent Nhibernate.

```
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Table("Employees");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.FirstName)
           .Column("EmpFirstName");
        Map(x => x.LastName);
           .Column("EmpLastName")
        References(x => x.Store);
     }
 }
```

But instead of having the names I specified, the table and column names that appeared in my Postgresql db are all in lower case i.e. Employees -> employees and EmpFirstName -> empfirstname.

How can I set my table and column names to have the exact letter cases that I specified in my employee mapping?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer Sly's answer but you can get away with this (but it's ugly):

```
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Table("Employees");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.FirstName)
           .Column("\"EmpFirstName\"");
        Map(x => x.LastName);
           .Column("\"EmpLastName\"")
        References(x => x.Store);
     }
 }
```

*EDIT* here is link how to implement this via a naming strategy:
http://manfredlange.blogspot.com/2011/04/fluent-nhibernate-postgresql-and.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to setup [autoquote](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/06/24/auto-quote-table-column-names.aspx) option for NHibernate.

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">auto-quote</property>
```

My gues the problem is in [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-syntax.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> the identifiers FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo" and "FOO" are different from these three and each other.

Comment: @OP : look here how to implement this in FNH -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438491/fluent-nhibernate-and-postgresql-schemametadataupdater-quotetableandcolumns-s