# NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException why?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, exception, ado.net, fluent-nhibernate

I have this

```
  return session.Query<CoursePermission>().Where(x => x.Student.StudentId == studentId).ToList();
```

I get this

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException was unhandled by user code
  Message=could not execute query
[ select courseperm0_.PermissionId as Permissi1_3_, courseperm0_.Owner as Owner3_, courseperm0_.Add as Add3_, courseperm0_.Edit as Edit3_, courseperm0_.Delete as Delete3_, courseperm0_.View as View3_, courseperm0_.StudentId as StudentId3_, courseperm0_.CourseId as CourseId3_ from CoursePermissions courseperm0_ where courseperm0_.StudentId=@p0 ]
  Name:p1 - Value:757f27a2-e997-44f8-b2c2-6c0fd6ee2c2f
[SQL: select courseperm0_.PermissionId as Permissi1_3_, courseperm0_.Owner as Owner3_, courseperm0_.Add as Add3_, courseperm0_.Edit as Edit3_, courseperm0_.Delete as Delete3_, courseperm0_.View as View3_, courseperm0_.StudentId as StudentId3_, courseperm0_.CourseId as CourseId3_ from CoursePermissions courseperm0_ where courseperm0_.StudentId=@p0]
  Source=NHibernate
  SqlString=select courseperm0_.PermissionId as Permissi1_3_, courseperm0_.Owner as Owner3_, courseperm0_.Add as Add3_, courseperm0_.Edit as Edit3_, courseperm0_.Delete as Delete3_, courseperm0_.View as View3_, courseperm0_.StudentId as StudentId3_, courseperm0_.CourseId as CourseId3_ from CoursePermissions courseperm0_ where courseperm0_.StudentId=@p0
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes)
       at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Loader.QueryLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLQueryPlan.PerformList(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session, IList results)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters parameters)
       at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionQueryImpl.List()
       at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression, IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery)
       at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
       at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
       at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at PermissionLevelRepo.GetPermission(Guid studentId) line 28
       at For(String email) in :line 63
       at (String email) in :line 50
       at PlannerController.Tab() :line 43
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
       Message=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Add'.
       Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
       ErrorCode=-2146232060
       Class=15
       LineNumber=1
       Number=156
       Procedure=""
       Server=mssql.frostyserver.com
       State=1
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
            at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       InnerException:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like `StudentId` is a `Guid`. Try:

```
return session
  .Query<CoursePermission>()
  .Where(x => x.Student.StudentId.Equals(studentId))
  .ToList();
```

EDIT: The inner exception:

```
Message=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Add'
```

The generated sql has a column called Add, try renaming this in your mapping rules.

```
select courseperm0_.PermissionId as Permissi1_3_, courseperm0_.Owner as Owner3_, courseperm0_.Add as Add3_, ...
```

Comment: I get a not supported exception(Boolean Equals(System.Guid)). What I have done I done it before with Guids. If I do return session.Query<CoursePermission>() it works.

Comment: Grab the generated sql and try running it directly against your db

Comment: I get the same sort of error - Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Add'. I will post my db table(I do have a column called Add not sure why it is calling it though)

Comment: @Johathan - Ah now I see it is some keyword from ms sql I guess. I had to do this on another table(because I used "where"). I think what through me off is I was not doing anything with the "add" column.

Comment: in your mapping you need to escape the column name Add as it is a reserved word in MSSQL, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545120/fluent-nhibernate-column-mapping-with-reserved-word