# Nhibernate, how to using sql server keyword as table name?

Tags: nhibernate, s#arp-architecture, s#arp

I am building my application using s#arp lite framework. One of my tables is called `User`. But `User` is a SQL Server 2008 keyword, so it gives me problems.

I tried to modify the code to support tables using SQL Server keywords, butcouldn't get it to work.

Here's the code.

https://github.com/codai/Sharp-Lite/blob/master/Example/MyStore/app/MyStore.NHibernateProvider/Conventions.cs

Line 32:  I changed it to following code

```
classCustomizer.Table("[" + Inflector.Net.Inflector.Singularize(type.Name.ToString()) + "]");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already answered this on the mailing list, posting answer here for others to find easily (and the points :)

https://github.com/codai/Sharp-Lite/blob/master/Example/MyStore/app/MyStore.NHibernateProvider/NHibernateInitializer.cs#L19

add:
db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote;

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This seems vaguely familiar to me.
No promises but you can try to use quotes around User, like select * from "User"
or
supply the schema owner ase well, like select * from Mydb.User.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your help, tried using quotes around User, not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this manually by utilizing NHibernate's non-DB specific escape character: the backtick `

In SQL Server you may do "[User]" but in Oracle it will be different. If you use "`User`" NHibernate will adapt this to the database you are currently working with.

This can be seen on this question: [Fluent NHibernate Column Mapping with Reserved Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545120/fluent-nhibernate-column-mapping-with-reserved-word)